# How to use coordinate layout with custom view..?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

How can i apply collapsing toolbar/Appbar functionality to an imageview or to a layout...???

I know this is possible for Toolbar/Appbar using com.android.support:design library but how to apply this to a layout/Custom view..???

Comment: There's no difference, a view is a view.

Answer (score 0):

You can put anything inside an [AppBarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html) and set the appropiate flags to make it scroll up and down like a toolbar would. Also, remeber that the `Toolbar` is a subclass of `ViewGroup` so you can puts views inside it.